# How to splice an empty property of an object that's into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, splice

So I have an array of objects and I would like to slice the property of an object when it's empty.

For example:

```
var quotes = [
{
    quote: "Bolshevism is not a policy; it is a disease. It is not a creed; it is a pestilence.",
    source: "Winston Churchill",
    citation: "",
    year: "29 May 1919",
    place: ""
},
{
    quote: "Learn while you live",
    source: "",
    citation: "X",
    year: "1950",
    place: ""
}];
```

I have a list of objects like that with object names randomly empty.

I would like to print to the page only the properties that are not empty.

So I'm trying to loop through the object to find the indexOf() the empty property and splice it:

```
function findEmptyProp(quotes) {
   for (prop in quotes) {
     if(quotes[i].children === '') {
        return indexOf(quotes[i]);
        quotes.splice(i, 1);
}}}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Objects have no order, slicing them on an offset is pretty nonsensical.

Comment: What exactly should the result be, for this example data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

splice is used for arrays, but when you deal with objects, you have to use `delete`.

You can try something like this:

```js
var quotes = [{
  quote: "Bolshevism is not a policy; it is a disease. It is not a creed; it is a pestilence.",
  source: "Wyston Churchill",
  citation: "",
  year: "29 May 1919",
  place: ""
}, {
  quote: "Learn while you live",
  source: "",
  citation: "X",
  year: "1950",
  place: ""
}];

quotes.forEach(function(o){
  for (var k in o){
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(k) && isEmpty(o[k])){
      delete o[k];
    }
  }
});

function isEmpty(val){
  return val === undefined || 
    val === null || 
    (typeof(val) === "object" && Object.keys(val).length === 0) || 
    (typeof(val) === "string" && val.trim().length === 0)
}

console.log(quotes)
```

As commented by [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze), I have added handling for other cases where value can be considered as empty. Also you should check for `hasOwnProperty` to update properties of itself.

Comment: You might want to consider the possibility of values other than strings (`trim()` would fail) and `hasOwnProperty`… but yes, that's the right approach.

Comment: @deceze I have tried to add handling for other empty cases. Thanks

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

FYI: Using `Object.keys(obj)` returns an array of, unsurprisingly, an object's keys.  E.g. ...

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    prop1: '1',
    prop2: '2',
    prop3: ''
  },
  {
    prop1: '1',
    prop2: '',
    prop3: '3'
  },
  {
    prop1: '',
    prop2: '2',
    prop3: '3'
  }
];

arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
    /* 'obj' = each object in 'arrayOfObjects' */
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        /* 'key' = each key in 'obj' */
        if (obj[key] === '') delete obj[key];
    });
});

/* test arrayOfObjects */
arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
    console.debug(obj);
});

/** =>
    Object { prop1: "1", prop2: "2" }
    Object { prop1: "1", prop3: "3" }
    Object { prop2: "2", prop3: "3" }
**/
```

Using array-functions like `.forEach()`, `.filter()`, `.sort()`, `.reduce()`, and `.map()` etc on Objects can be really handy.

Comment: Thanks for the input, very much appreciated!